# import org.apache.poi error, maven progject error netbeans

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

[Import error messages for apoche.poi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skn4S.jpg) I have been updating an application for work and it hasn't been touched for a while so it has some old imports or versions that need to be updated. I'm having issues with creating a build or exportable version of the updated app as I get this build error along with import errors regarding org.apache.poi:

cd C:\Users\ALC\Desktop\ode-suite; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144" cmd /c "\"\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath ode.MainApp\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom

---

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 5.488s
Finished at: Tue Apr 14 17:02:32 EDT 2020

### Final Memory: 7M/123M

Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Comment: The problem is **Failed to transfer file:** http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase: **HTTPS Required**.  Do using `HTTPS`: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom. `https://repo.maven...` instead of `http://repo.maven...`.

Comment: See also https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334